# VPC peering of existing vpc and subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

How can I perform VPC peering between an existing VPC and subnet?

I have two VPC CIDRs. First is `192.168.0.0/16` and second is `10.0.0.0/16` with existing subnet CIDR `192.168.1.0/24` and `10.0.1.0/24`.

So if I choose [this CloudFormation template](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rkstar/CF/vpc_peering.txt) it will create a new VPC that I don't want. I want the existing VPC and subnet with peering.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

VPC Peering takes place between two VPCs. The subnets are automatically peered when the VPCs are peered.

The CloudFormation template you referenced creates new VPCs. If you want to peer existing VPCs, then you should remove the VPC and Subnet definitions from the template, otherwise it will create new ones.

You will need to add additional parameters into the template to ask which VPCs you wish to peer, and then use those values in the peering definition.

Remember -- everything defined in the `Resources` section will be created. If you don't want them created, you can instead refer to existing resources.

Comment: Thanks bro due to your valuable comment i resloved my issue and create new template for vpc peering for same account